# QVideoWidget stand alone. How to stop video when window closes?

Tags: c++, qt5.5

I have the following

```
QVideoWidget* vw = new QVideoWidget;
QMediaResource mr(QUrl::fromLocalFile(item->data(Qt::UserRole + FilepathRole).toString()));
QMediaContent mc(mr);
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;
QObject::connect(vw,SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)),player,SLOT(stop()));
player->setMedia(mc);
player->setVideoOutput(vw);
QRect rect = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
int width = vids[vids.indexOf(item->data(Qt::UserRole + FilepathRole).toString())].width;
int height = vids[vids.indexOf(item->data(Qt::UserRole + FilepathRole).toString())].height;
int x = (rect.width() / 2) - (width / 2);
int y = (rect.height() / 2) - (height / 2);
vw->setGeometry(x,y,width,height);
vw->show();
player->play();
```

everything works except that when I close the window for the QVideoWidget that pops up the video keeps playing somewhere, or at least the sound does. I thought that connect line would do the trick but it does not. What is the correct way to stop playback when closing the QVideoWidget window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the window is not destroyed when you close it, so `stop` does not actually get called. You can to set the  [`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) using the [`QWidget::setAttribute()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setAttribute) to change the behaviour.

```
vw->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose );
```

Comment: this worked after I corrected my connect call with vw instead of vw->parent()